# Widget colours aren't changing

Tags: python-3.x, widget, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently learning about widgets in jupyter notebook python 3.7 The colors iv set to change my widgets arent changing, is there an update or something else I need to install?

This is what I'm refering too:
[image: This is what I'm refering too]

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention it as button_color and for instance, refer to the code below

`Button(description='Header', layout=Layout(width='auto', grid_area='header'), style=ButtonStyle(button_color='lightblue'))`